# Modifying JSON data for API

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have built an API which essentially has three calls.  Firstly, a call is made to retrieve a token.  Next, I have a type of autocomplete feature which returns data and the coresponding table it should look up.  This data is returned like so

```
[
  {
    "result": "Apples",
    "table": "fruitTable"
  },
  {
    "result": "Bread",
    "table": "breadTable"
  },
  {
    "result": "Pie",
    "table": "pieTable"
  }
]
```

My final route is like the following

```
Route::get('returnSelectedResult/{table}/{selected}', array('uses'=>'APIController@returnSelectedResult'));
```

Whereby it uses the lookup results above to get the right table and the selected option.  Then I do the following

```
public function returnSelectedResult($table, $selected)
{
    $tableData = DB::table($table)->where('search_item', $selected)->get();
    return response($tableData, 200);
}
```

So this all works fine.  However, the data in the table is flat.  So the final thing returned to the user of the API is something like this

```
[
  {
    "search_item": "Bread",
    "num_types": 34,
    "most_ordered": 'Baggette',
    "most_popular_day": 'Saturday',
    "average_profit": 3.5,
  }
]
```

What I am showing is a very cut down version, there is a lot more data returned but it is all at the same level.  What I need to return to the user is something more along the 
lines of this

```
[
  {
    "searched" : {
        "search_item": "Bread"
    },
    "types" : {
        "num_types": 34
    },
    "analytics" : {
        "most_ordered": 'Baggette',
        "most_popular_day": 'Saturday',
        "average_profit": 3.5
    }
  }
]
```

What would be the best way to achieve something like this?

Thanks

Comment: The best way is to reformat your array like you need

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly build the array with the query results.

Comment: I was confused whether to do this, or if I needed to Model things.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to build api you should use transformers for a better presentation of data .

you can use phpleague/fractal or if you want full api package  i recommend you to try dingo/api .

Comment: fractal looks interesting, will take a look into it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,
Now I have done for analytics

```
class MainClass
{
  public $searched;
  public $types;
  public $analytics;
}

class AnalyticsClass
{
  public $most_ordered;
  public $most_popular_day;
  public $average_profit;
}

$obj_data = new AnalyticsClass();
$obj_data->most_ordered = 'Baggette';  
$obj_data->most_popular_day = 'Saturday';
$obj_data->average_profit = 3.5;

$obj_main = new MainClass();
$obj_main->analytics = $obj_data;
```